# MVC app suddenly requiring authorization for everything after Windows/IIS reinstall

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I recently reinstalled Windows (on an SSD!) and I'm in the process of setting up IIS and all my web projects.

One of my MVC project keeps asking for authentication on everything, including on resources like .css files and images. I'm using the default MVC template login with a custom provider that I'm using for dev purposes.

I've tried rolling back my web.config to before I moved the project file and re-set IIS, but that didn't make much of a difference -- aside from changing authentication mode from Windows to Forms.

Can you see anything wrong with my config?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="SuperSimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SuperSimpleMembershipProvider" type="Website.Helpers.SuperSimpleMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I don't have any `<authorization>` element or anything else related to login, since I'm doing everything via MVC.

Update: Tried `<authorization><allow users="*"/></authorization>`, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had too allow IUSR read access to the site folder, since that's the user that Anonymous Authentication allows.

Comment: Can you explain little bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the configuration settings in IIS for that particular website?  There are authentication options there which will help.

Comment: Yep, it actually just modifies the web.config file -- so it's the same thing.